# asymptotic expansion of an integral at order $6$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics

> Find an asymptotic expansion at order $6$ of $f(x) = \int_x^{x^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$

I don't know how to proceed. I think I need to do a change of variable yet I don't know which one. I tried $u = t/x$ yet it doens't seem to work...

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are looking for an expansion as $x\rightarrow 0$.

For $u\rightarrow 0$, 
$$(1+u)^\alpha = 1 + \alpha u + \mathcal O(u^2)$$
Therefore
$$\frac 1 {\sqrt{1+t^4}}=1 -\frac 1 2 t^4 +\mathcal O(t^{8})$$
and 
$$\begin{split}
f(x) &= \int_x^{x^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\\
&=\int_x^{x^2}\left(1-\frac 1 2 t^4+\mathcal O\left(t^8\right)\right)dt\\
&= (x^2-x)-\frac 1 2\left(\frac{x^{10}}{5}-\frac{x^5}5\right)+\mathcal O\left(x^9\right)\\
&=-x +x^2+\frac{x^5}{10}+\mathcal O\left(x^9\right)
\end{split}$$

Answer (score 0):

You want
$f(x) = \int_x^{x^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}
$
to order 6.

Being as general as possible,
let
$f(x) 
= \int_{x^a}^{x^b} (1+t^u)^v dt
$.

Then,
using the generalized binomial theorem,

$\begin{array}\\
f(x) 
&= \int_{x^a}^{x^b} (1+t^u)^v dt\\
&= \int_{x^a}^{x^b} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{v}{n}t^{un}dt\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{v}{n}\int_{x^a}^{x^b} t^{un}dt\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{v}{n}\dfrac{t^{un+1}}{un+1}|_{x^a}^{x^b} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{v}{n}\dfrac{(x^b)^{un+1}-(x^a)^{un+1}}{un+1} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{v}{n}\dfrac{x^{b(un+1)}-x^{a(un+1)}}{un+1} \\
\end{array}
$

Then take as many terms as you want.